# Jquery Mobile, not working dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I can not see why it is not working this dialog. I am using jqm 1.3

```
<a href="#foo" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>

<div id="foo" data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Delete page?</h1>
        <p>This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute.</p>
        <a href="dialog/index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="dialog/index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added on the "head"

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js>
```

and others jqm events are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your anchor tag which invokes the dialog inside a page div as given below.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
<a href="#foo" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="foo" data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Delete page?</h1>
        <p>This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute.</p>
        <a href="dialog/index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b">Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="dialog/index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check out an example at <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/y5Ttv/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much, you save me Mayu.
In my case I had to move outside data-role="page" my div with the content.

Comment: Glad I could help you out :)

Comment: Worth to explicitly mention: <div data-role="page"> and <div id="foo" data-role="dialog"> must be the same level in HTML.